# How to get Yii version from html source

Tags: php, html, yii

I have to maintain an internal app in our company which is written in Yii.

Currently I do not have access to the source code.

I would like to know **which version of the Yii framework** (version 1.x or version 2.x) is used.

My idea is to get the version out of the Html source? e.g. directly or from includes as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/78d25e0f/css/yiistrap.min.css" />
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/8b843a06/jui/js/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

Are there any other hints to the Yii version?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current js which are associate with either grid or active form and based on that file you can verify from the yii source code. As per your current files it seems like its Yii1